# how to change Windows 10 Alt+Tab to Windows+Tab

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, alt-tab

After having used Mac + Virtualbox Ubuntu Linux for 3 years, I switched to Windows 10 + Virtualbox Ubuntu Linux recently, and I am trying to set things up similarly to how they were. Here is what I would like to do:
- On the Windows host, replace the Alt+Tab functionality with Windows+Tab.
- On the Virtualbox Ubuntu, now that Alt+Tab is free to use, use it to switch between windows inside Ubuntu, without leaving the Virtualbox environment.

I have seen lots of posts mentioning the behaviour of Alt+Tab in Windows 10, but none explaining how to flip over the Alt+Tab to Windows+Tab shortcut.

Any ideas how to do this?

EDIT: I should clarity that I've setup the 'Host' key to 'None' so that it wouldn't interfere with the guest keyboard shortcuts. I think it was the right-hand side Ctrl by default, which I use in Virtualbox Ubuntu Linux as much as the left-hand side Ctrl.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're probably out of luck.  One of the big limitations of WIndows when compared to macOS and most UNIX desktops is that it's damn near impossible to change most of the OS-provided hotkey combinations.

Comment: oh, well, it doesn't look easy then.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually one of my biggest personal issues with Windows, although not because of the Alt-Tab behavior (I want to use the virtual desktop support on Windows, but I don't want to have to memorize a dozen new hotkeys with 2-3 modifiers each).

Comment: 2 Years later, saw this as I was about to ask the same question. Anyone know of any changes or updates?